# SQL Server Reporting Services (Overwrite Dataset)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I created a paginated report using SQL Server Reporting Services and attached a dataset to pull a specific query from the database. However, I would like when I create a schedule for that report, for the **delivery dataset** to be used instead of the **report dataset**. Is this possible?

The reason being I want not only for the scheduled report to output one report per row in the database table but that each report only contains its respective row of data. What would you advise? Do let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: "schedule" = subscription, in your terminology?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jw11432 That is correct.

Comment: What I would do is create two reports: one that is shown for your users who access the report in real time using the report dataset, and then another report that remains hidden that uses the delivery dataset just for subscriptions.

Comment: @jw11432 , that would do the trick. Thanks much.